# Swift - Updating the view with data from an async method

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, ios9

I'm new to swift and working with async code.

I have a method that grabs data from an API, puts the data into objects and puts those objects into an array. I would then like to update the UI with data from those objects in the array.

To illustrate the UI getting updated, I'll change the value of a label.

Because the method that grabs info from the API is async, I can't return a value from it. Instead I pass a callback:

```
@IBOutlet var labelTest: UILabel!
private var eventsArray : Array<Event> = Array<Event>()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    APIAccessUtil.getEventsFromAPI({(eventsList: Array<Event>) -> Void in
        self.eventsArray = eventsList
    })

    sleep(5) //this is of course not good, but I'll leave it here to illustrate what's going on. 

    self.labelTest.text = eventsArray[0].description

}
```

This *works* because making the thread sleep will kind of leave time for the array to be filled up. However, making the main thread sleep is a really bad idea and there is no guarantee that data will be returned in this time.

If the `sleep(...)` is removed, then the UI label is attempted to be updated before the `getEventsFromAPI` call has completed, producing a runtime error (since the array will still be nil).

Attempt 2:

```
@IBOutlet var labelTest: UILabel!
private var eventsArray : Array<Event> = Array<Event>()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    APIAccessUtil.getEventsFromAPI({(eventsList: Array<Event>) -> Void in
        self.eventsArray = eventsList
        self.labelTest.text = eventsArray[0].description
    }) 
}
```

In attempt #2, I'm updating the UI from a background thread, which isn't good and produces the following warning:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

So, is there any way to update the UI from the main thread (i.e. change the label text) after the `getEventsFromAPI` call has completed (so that the array instance variable now is not nil)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. The final trick is to call the UI update from the main thread:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    APIAccessUtil.getEventsFromAPI({(eventsList: Array<Event>) -> Void in
        self.eventsArray = eventsList

        // Update the UI on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {          
            self.labelTest.text = eventsArray[0].description
        }           
    })
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your help! I'll accept the answer once the time limit is up.

Comment: this approach no longer seems to work, I get this error: `'dispatch_async' has been replaced by instance method 'DispatchQueue.async(execute:)'`

Comment: @Kinergy try this: `DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.labelTest.text = eventsArray[0].description
    }`

Comment: Hello. Do you have any other options? I used this solution and viewDidLoad still ignore my function which defined with CompletionBlock.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, this can be done a little more simply:

```
APIAccessUtil.getEventsFromAPI({(eventsList: Array<Event>) -> Void in
    self.eventsArray = eventsList

    // Update the UI on the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.labelTest.text = eventsArray[0].description
    }
})
```